# delete element in firebase with android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase data structure which looks like this:

```
    |---employees
         |----KJSXd4ScEmJ6N4UFc5k 
             |---employeeName:"semah"
             |---employeeAge:"24"
         |----KJW3HRh5kxm_FgU9nNV
             |---employeeName:"Alex"
             |---employeeAge:"35"
```

Now I want to delete the node -KJSXd4ScEmJ6N4UFc5k. But I only know the "employeeName": semah.
I tried to delete the node with:

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference
.child("employees")
.child("employeeName")
.child("semah")
.getParent()
.setValue(null);
```

but this won't work because "Invalid Firebase Database path: $member. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'"

So my question is, how can I delete the node: "-KJSXd4ScEmJ6N4UFc5k" only knowing: "semah" or how to remove element by the generated id "-KJSXd4ScEmJ6N4UFc5k".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no one have an answer to my question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have the reference to the key `KJSXd4ScEmJ6N4UFc5k`, you need to retrieve the value and try deleting it with the ref of value retrieved. Something like this

```
 database.getReference("employees").orderByChild("employeeName").equalTo("semah").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                child.getRef().setValue(null);
            }
        }


       @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
              Log.w("TodoApp", "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
         }
});
```

Comment: is there a method in firebae for java to get the key "KJSXd4ScEmJ6N4UFc5k" ??

Comment: this method will get you that value and you can use `dataSnapshot.getKey() ` in the `onDataChange` to get the key. My code will remove the value for that ref which will be same.

Comment: how i can use the method removeValue () ??

Comment: i have added the code that shows how it is used. what more do you need ? calling `setValue(null)` or `removeValue()` does the same thing. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#delete_data

Comment: but there is a problem ,if in the firebase there are two employeeName who have the same value ,how to know what value to delete so in this case we should know the key generated by firebase ?

Comment: they must be unique element right ? some other value must be different and you should compare that.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can build a query to retrieve the item to delete.
Something like:

```
Firebase refEmployees = new Firebase("..../employees");
Query queryRef = refEmployees.orderByChild("name").equalTo("semah");


queryRef..addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             String key=snapshot.getKey(); 
             //Remove the item
        }


       @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

         }
});
```

Comment: how to remove a child when added ,i want to remove an element from firebase not on adding

Comment: Just retrieve the data from the query with a listener to get the item to delete.